# How can I link to an item I don't have in the chat in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I found an item on WoWhead that I want crafting.  How can I link to it in the chat so I can find a crafter to make it for me?

Is there an addon or just some sort of chat magic I need to do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Wowhead, there is a "link" button on each item, glyph, weapon, etc. page.  This link will provide you with a "Script" that will look up the item for you in the game.

You can find it in the top right corner.

[image]

If you copy the text, and then enter it into your chat box in the game, it will put the item link right in your chat window.  Then, you can shift-click to link it to the crafter.

Comment: I think you're getting more upvotes than me *solely* because Awesome Boots > everything else.

Comment: @Raven You may be right, when I went to wowhead to decide which item to use I thought to myself, what would be an "awesome" item? Much to my satisfaction, these ilvl 21 boots are all the awesome I needed.

Comment: For me, Perdition's Blade has nostalgia. I won one the eve the Burning Crusade launched. I replaced it 2 days later. :(

Comment: Agreed, those items in particular like trinkets and weapons, that you waited to see drop, or you rolled terrible on for months at time, that you finally acquired, it's always such a let down when you have to replace them.  It is probably why my bank has more nostalgia items in it than it does useful ones.

Comment: Sorry Raven, awesome boots clenches it.  (also, sorry for late response, went away for the weekend)

Answer (score 9):

You don't need an addon of any sort! Since you've specified WoWhead, you've made it quite easy on yourself, as WoWhead is conducive to these sorts of things!

First, navigate to the item in question: I used "Perdition's Blade". Second, look for the small "Link" button, circled, below, in orange:
[image]

The following text-box will pop up.
[image]

Copy the string, and paste when you're in-game. Voila.